# REST API: How to get the n most recent items in ascending order

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-js-core, pnpjs, orderby

This seems like a very basic question but I can't figure it out. Using pnpjs I want to retrieve the 50 most recently created items, oldest first, newest last.

I can only manage to get them in the wrong order:

```
 const items = await this.spClient.web.lists.getByTitle(this.spList).items
            .top(50)
            .orderBy("Created",false)
            .get();
```

If I change this to

```
 const items = await this.spClient.web.lists.getByTitle(this.spList).items
            .top(50)
            .orderBy("Created",true)
            .get();
```

the order is right but I get the 50 **first** items.

So how to get the items I want sorted the way I want?

Comment: Not able to reproduce. Your code is working at my end. Which pnp js are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to do both the REST `orderBy`, and then use JavaScript to [reverse the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) of items in the returned results.

The problem is thus:  In order for the REST API to return only the *n* most recent items, you have to provide the ODATA `orderBy` the created date in **Descending** order.  But, if you want to use or display those same *n* items in any other order than that which you retrieved, you will need to re-sort the results in your code.

Comment: Thank you. I was afraid I'd have to do this. Now I know.

Answer (score 1):

We can also use caml query to get the 50 items and sorted. Below is not an exact working code, I haven't tested, but it will give you an idea to implement it.

```
const xml = "<View><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='ID' /><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Created' /></OrderBy></Query><RowLimit>50</RowLimit></View>";    
const q: CamlQuery = {
    ViewXml: xml,
};    
const items = pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("SPPnPJSExampleList").getItemsByCAMLQuery(q)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using below if this works for you:

```
const items = await this.spClient.web.lists.getByTitle(this.spList).items
             .orderBy("Created",true)
             .top(50)
             .get();
```

For descending order you can use `orderBy("Created, false)`.

Update:

As @willman mentioned, You need to get the data in reverse order using `orderBy("Created, false)` and then you need to reverse the array in your code when you get the complete data.

[PnPJS - Working With: Items](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Working-With:-Items).

Comment: Also, you can try passing `ID` instead of `Created`.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't give me the correct data. It gets the 50 oldest entries sorted from old to new. I want the 50 newest entries sorted from old to new. With `.orderBy("Created",false)` I get the 50 newest entries but sorted from new to old. Swapping `top` and `orderBy` doesn't change anything.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your question. I thought you want the items created first. My bad.